# How do I open a specific MS Project 2007 file from the command line?

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2007

How do I open a specific MS Project 2007 file from the command line? I've tried the simple-minded:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\winproj.EXE" "%1"
```

However this doesn't open the passed file argument. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer.  It seems that you need to have the full path to the file you're talking about for the command line to work.  In my batch file to do that I've coded it as:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\winproj.EXE" "%CD%\%1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try as filename without quotation marks?:

```
"c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\winproj.exe" filename.mpp
```